# ajaxSubmitButton Yii Framework does not save the data

Tags: ajax, yii

I cannot figure out how to save my form with the AjaxSubmitButton.

Which url should I use in the following command ?

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
                    'AjaxSave',
                    Yii::app()->createUrl('WHich URL ?'),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'POST',
                        'dataType'=>'json',
                        'success'=>'js:function(data){
                            alert("commentSubmitted");}',
                        'error'=>'js:function(data){
                            alert("comment NOT Submitted");}',  
                        )
        );
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what do u mean by "which url"?

Answer (score 0):

The url to your controller/action that deals with the submission